# Segfault 11 with NSBundle(forClass:) and multiple type constraint (protocol + class)

Tags: class, swift, compilation

The following code runs fine in the Simulator but throws "**Command failed du to signal: Segmentation fault: 11**" when creating an Archive.

```
func popAction() {
  MyViewController.pop(self)
}

class func pop<T where T : MyActionDelegate, T : UIViewController>(controller: T) {
   let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: controller.dynamicType)
   // …
}
```

The following compiles just fine:

```
let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: object_getClass(self))
// or
let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self)
```

dynamicType seems to have an issue with the type composition (a protocol and a class).

I suppose the reason why this would work in debug mode and not in release mode lies somewhere in the optimization performed during compilation.

Can anyone tell me more about why it would work in one case and not the other?

Thanks

Comment: What if you throw it in a variable first? `let controllerClass: AnyClass = controller.dynamicType` or `let controllerClass: AnyClass = (controller as AnyObject).dynamicType`.

Comment: @fluidsonic I get the same error

Comment: Can you please post more of your code? The two functions must be part of a class. I just tried your code with empty `MyActionDelegate` and `MyViewController` in Playground and it compiles and runs just fine.

Comment: @fluidsonic The issue occurs when building an **Archive**, which is something you can't do in Playground. It runs fine in the Playground, and it compiles and run in the Simulator and in a dev device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me even with optimizations turned on:

```
func popAction() {
    MyViewController.pop(self)
}

class func pop<T where T : MyActionDelegate, T : UIViewController>(controller: T) {
    let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: (controller as UIViewController).dynamicType)
    // …
}
```

Comment: I'll vote it up but can't accept it. My question is not about finding a solution that works, I gave 2 examples that do compile too. I want to understand why dynamicType gets confused when building an Archive specifically.

Comment: @Nycen the Swift compiler is still very young and full of bugs. I came across a lot of crashes which I had to work around. The problem is not the archiving process itself but that the **release** build configuration is used in this case which enables code optimizations. So in your case there's a bug in the Swift compiler's optimization code. Report any bugs you find Swift's compiler to Apple and also here if you like: https://github.com/practicalswift/swift-compiler-crashes

Comment: I guess we can assume it's a bug and I'll accept your global answer.